# How to enlarge a leaflet polygon box by 5%?

Tags: php, leaflet

I create a square polygon by using the min and max values of the latitude and longitude of the furtherst points of my incoming data.

```
$poly = " $maxLng $maxLat , $minLng $maxLat , $minLng $minLat , $maxLng $minLat , $maxLng $maxLat ";
```

But this means that at least two markers are always the borders of this box. How can I push out the points and enlarge the overall size of the box by say 5% in all directions but I still need the lat/lon of each of those corners?

Comment: What language are you working in? You added the `leaflet` tag but that doesn't look like Javascript.

Comment: @IvanSanchez Ooops, I put the PHP that creates the javascript variable in by mistake. The important thing is the variables I used from the table are represented, it was more of an example than the exact thing.

Comment: I think you should clarify whether you want this to e handled in the PHP side or the JS side (or any), and whether the 5% increase relates to visible (screen) size, size in degrees, or size in meters (as the three things are different).

Comment: @IvanSanchez OK, let me ask you to help me make it a better question. Right now I create the 4 corners by taking the point furthest to the north west, furthest to the south east as my boundaries. Maybe I should be using something else, what should I be using? And making this a javascript answer would work, because it all gets moved to that anyway.

Comment: I've added or subtracted 0̷.2 as appropriate to each of the minimum/maximum latitudes and longitudes. This is a nice stop-gap but some way to do this with leaflet would be nicer and give more consistency to the look and feel of the map.

Comment: See this library [transformScale](https://turfjs.org/docs/#transformScale), it may help you with what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 3):

A small example of how to use the `turfjs` library and the `transformScale` method

```js
const map = L.map('mapid').setView([52.308478623663355, 19.281005859375004], 6);

L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
  maxZoom: 18,
  attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(map);


const test = [
  [54.80068486732236, 18.292236328125004],
  [53.89786522246521, 14.611816406250002],
  [51.055207338584964, 15.281982421875002],
  [49.57510247172322, 19.138183593750004],
  [50.57626025689928, 23.642578125000004],
  [52.214338608258224, 23.148193359375004],
  [52.86912972768522, 23.741455078125],
  [54.29729354239267, 22.928466796875004],
  [54.29729354239267, 19.489746093750004],
  [54.80068486732236, 18.292236328125004]
];

L.polygon(test, {
  color: 'red'
}).addTo(map);

var poly = turf.polygon([test]);
var scaledPoly = turf.transformScale(poly, 1.05);

const {
  coordinates
} = scaledPoly.geometry;

L.polygon(coordinates, {
  color: 'white'
}).addTo(map);
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  min-height: 100%;
}

#mapid {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.6.0/dist/leaflet.css" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.6.0/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@turf/turf@5/turf.min.js"></script>


<div id="mapid"></div>
```

Comment: @Grzegorz_T. This looks fantastic. I knew someone must know of a cleaner way to do it than what I did. I'll give it a try right now.